# Reg Ex to find '+' or '-' sign in Python

Tags: python, regex, expression

```
Row2 = re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?', str (table))
```

Hi all, this is my regular expression. I'm not sure how to alter it in order to also make it display the values that I have scraped with the + or - sign before the figures. For example, my output is '47.31' but its supposed to be '+47.31'.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `[+-]?` at the beginning of your regex to match those characters:

```
Row2 = re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?', str (table))
```

Comment: I tried doing this myself, and it never worked for some reason. But tried yours and it works perfectly! Thank you. Just another quick question, once you have done that. My outcome is like this: ['7,415.95', '+47.31', '+0.64', '7,444.62', '7,368.64', '7,368.64'] ... How would i get rid of the speech marks and brackets etc to just show as figures? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how should it look like ?

Comment: It should look like this: 7,415.95  +47.31  +0.64  7,444.62  7,368.64  7,368.64  ... I want to preview it on Python like a table you see with two rows. So the top row would be Value , +/- , %+/-  , High , Low , Prev and Close.

Comment: You could change the way you print the result (use a `for` loop for example to display the results)

Comment: so how would I use the for loop to turn it into a table?

Comment: I do not understand your values and how you want to display them, but you can start with `for val in Row2:
        print val`

Comment: Right so I wanted to print them horizontally. I've got that, but I want to add headings above the values. Not so sure how to do that, i know it would be using a for loop... But how would I make the headings print so it looks neat and tidy? Thanks in advance.